# How to randomize functions inside a list?

Tags: python, selenium, random

I've written a script that logs in to instagram using Selenium, searches for a tag and clicks on the 3 first pictures from left to right.

It first opens the first picture from left to right at the first row, then likes the picture, and then closes it and moves to the next one.

For each picture I wrote a function Pic_1(), Pic_2(), Pic_(3).
And placed it inside a list.

Then I use the shuffle method in order to avoid getting spoted by Instagram. However, when I use the shuffle method (I also tried with choice) it still goes from picture 1 to 3 and don't randomize as I'd like.

```
def Pic_1():
    #Picture 1 from Left to Right
    search_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div'))
        ).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    #Like Button <3
    search_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button'))
        ).click()
    #Close Picture Button
    search_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/button'))
        ).click()
def Pic_2():
    #Picture 2 from Left to Right
    search_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]'))
        ).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    #Like Button <3
    search_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button'))
        ).click()
    #Close Picture Button
    search_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/button'))
        ).click()
def Pic_3():
    #Picture 3 from Left to Right
    search_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]'))
        ).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    #Like Button <3
    search_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button'))
        ).click()
    #Close Picture Button
    search_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/button'))
        ).click()

import random

mylist = [Pic_1(), Pic_2(), Pic_3()]

print(random.shuffle(mylist)
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call the functions in the list. You're calling the functions, then shuffling, but the functions have already been executed at that point, so you're just shuffling the `None`s that the functions return.

```
functions = [Pic_1, Pic_2, Pic_3]  # Not called!
random.shuffle(functions)

for f in functions:  # Loop over the shuffled functions
    f()
```

---

It seems though like the only things that differ in those functions is the `div[2]` part. You could generate a random number between 1-3 in the loop, pass the number in to a generic functions that plugs the data into the spot that differs. Then you just need to call the function in a loop with random numbers.

Comment: Hey man, that worked as a hot knife in butter. Beautifully efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can use `random.choice(mylist)` to get your goals, if you wanna really randomize the click behavior, cause it is also possible that a picture is clicked more than one time.

**Example**

```
import random
from time import sleep

def p():
    print ('p')
def pp():
    print('pp')
def ppp():
    print('ppp')

mylist = [p, pp, ppp]

for f in mylist:
    random.choice(mylist)()
    sleep(1)
```

*If this is not what you intend, `shuffle` should be your choice.

Comment: I have edited the example - Instead printing as in yours functions now will be called.